# Why does my collision group script not work

Tags: lua, roblox

So Im making a tower defense game in roblox and I'm trying to make it so that the enemies dont collide with eachother. I made the script with a old tutorial but i found the new methods for the collision groups and edited the piece of code but i keep getting an error saying "Collision group is not part of humanoid root part(of my enemy model)"
This is just a part of my whole module script that i made for spawning the enemies in and making them not collide with eachother but they still collide

```
            local newMob = mobExists:Clone()
            newMob.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = map.StartPoint.CFrame
            newMob.Parent = map.Mob
            
            for i, object in ipairs(newMob:GetDescendants()) do
                PhysicsService:RegisterCollisionGroup("Mobs")
                if object:IsA("BasePart") then
                    object:CollisionGroup(object, "Mobs")
                end
            end
```

I made the script expecting the enemies too not collide with eachother anymore but instead i got an error that doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `CollisionGroup` isn't a function on the object. It's a [property that you set](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BasePart#CollisionGroup).

There's an [official tutorial](https://create.roblox.com/docs/workspace/collision-filtering) you can follow on collision groups that's very helpful. So follow these steps :

1. Register the collision group (try to do this once)
2. Set the collision properties between the collision groups
3. Add objects to the new collision group

So try something like this :

```lua
local PhysicsService = game:GetService("PhysicsService")
local COLLISION_GROUP_MOBS = "Mobs"
local mobExists -- DEFINE THIS VARIABLE
local map -- DEFINE THIS VARIABLE TOO

-- Register the new collision group
PhysicsService:RegisterCollisionGroup(COLLISION_GROUP_MOBS)

-- Disable collisions between objects in the collision group
PhysicsService:CollisionGroupSetCollidable(COLLISION_GROUP_MOBS, COLLISION_GROUP_MOBS, false)

-- Create a helper function to spawn mobs
local function spawnMob()
    -- spawn and position the mob
    local newMob = mobExists:Clone()
    newMob:PivotTo(map.StartPoint.CFrame)
    newMob.Parent = map.Mob
    
    -- set every collidable part to the mob collision group
    for _, object in ipairs(newMob:GetDescendants()) do
        if object:IsA("BasePart") then
            object.CollisionGroup = COLLISION_GROUP_MOBS
        end
     end

    return newMob
end
```